# How to get byte representation of HTML response like with the Python 'requests' library 'response.content'

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, lxml

With the Python requests library, on getting a response, what is the exact representation of `response.content` including the UTF encoding?

---

How would I take a string or text (like `response.text`) and convert that to the exact representation that is `response.content`?

**Example:**

`response = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com')`

`response.content` is a byte representation.

If I were to take `response.text` how would I convert it to `response.content` in Python?

---

**Reason:**

I have another HTTP library that gets back a HTML response in String format (Selenium : `driver.page_source` ), and I need to pass that to another library `lxml` that only accepts the byte representation exactly as the requests `response.content` is formed.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the string format to `bytes` with an encoding (probably `'utf-8'`):

```py
import requests
response = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
response.content == response.text  # False
response.content == bytes(response.text, encoding='utf-8')  # True
```